# Unable to access workload at the IP address of the Kubernetes Service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a Load Balancer Service for my K8s Workload. I have exposed the workload as a service; however, I am unable to access the resource at the IP address of the service: `35.193.34.113:80`

My host port is **80** and target port is **9000**.

The following is the YAML configuration of my service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-18T06:15:14Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app: food-for-worms
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app: {}
      f:spec:
        f:allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: {}
        f:externalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:internalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:ports:
          .: {}
          k:{"port":80,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
            f:targetPort: {}
        f:selector: {}
        f:sessionAffinity: {}
        f:type: {}
    manager: GoogleCloudConsole
    operation: Update
    time: "2022-09-18T06:15:14Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:finalizers:
          .: {}
          v:"service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup": {}
      f:status:
        f:loadBalancer:
          f:ingress: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    subresource: status
    time: "2022-09-18T06:15:49Z"
  name: food-for-worms-service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "64162"
  uid: 2d541e31-0415-4583-a89f-7021d5984b50
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  clusterIP: 10.44.5.70
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.44.5.70
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31331
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: food-for-worms
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.193.34.113
```

The following is the YAML configuration of my workload:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "2"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-18T06:13:19Z"
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: food-for-worms
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app: {}
      f:spec:
        f:progressDeadlineSeconds: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
        f:selector: {}
        f:strategy:
          f:rollingUpdate:
            .: {}
            f:maxSurge: {}
            f:maxUnavailable: {}
          f:type: {}
        f:template:
          f:metadata:
            f:labels:
              .: {}
              f:app: {}
          f:spec:
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"node-app-1"}:
                .: {}
                f:image: {}
                f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:ports:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"containerPort":9000,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:containerPort: {}
                    f:protocol: {}
                f:resources: {}
                f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
            f:dnsPolicy: {}
            f:restartPolicy: {}
            f:schedulerName: {}
            f:securityContext: {}
            f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
    manager: GoogleCloudConsole
    operation: Update
    time: "2022-09-19T06:26:34Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: {}
      f:status:
        f:availableReplicas: {}
        f:conditions:
          .: {}
          k:{"type":"Available"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
        f:observedGeneration: {}
        f:readyReplicas: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:updatedReplicas: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    subresource: status
    time: "2022-09-19T06:26:38Z"
  name: food-for-worms
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "652865"
  uid: 4e085d08-433c-468b-8a4c-c11326594a2e
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: food-for-worms
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: food-for-worms
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/k8s-networking-test/node-app:v1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: node-app-1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 3
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-09-18T06:13:20Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-09-18T06:13:20Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-09-18T06:13:19Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-09-19T06:26:38Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "food-for-worms-76db78f674" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 2
  readyReplicas: 3
  replicas: 3
  updatedReplicas: 3
```

The following is the output to `kubectl describe service food-for-worms-service`:

```
Name:                     food-for-worms-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=food-for-worms
Annotations:              cloud.google.com/neg: {"ingress":true}
Selector:                 app=food-for-worms
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.44.5.70
IPs:                      10.44.5.70
LoadBalancer Ingress:     35.193.34.113
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               9000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31331/TCP
Endpoints:                10.40.6.3:9000,10.40.7.2:9000,10.40.8.2:9000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

The following is my `app.js` listening on port 9000:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 9000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Do not have an inflated sense of yourself. You are just food for worms.');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

The following is my Dockerfile code:

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.11
EXPOSE 9000
COPY app.js /
```

When I follow the link to `35.193.34.113:80` , I get the Page can't be reached error.

What am I missing here please?

Comment: What error are you seeing?  Also, can you share the spec for the deployment with the label `food-for-worms`?

Comment: Thanks @GariSingh I have updated my question with the YAML config for the workload.

Comment: Is your node-app actually listening on port 9000?

Comment: @Nosail you didn't define `containerPort` in Deployment manifest. I think this is your problem.

Comment: yes, my node-app is listening on port 9000. @xirehat where do I need to define that. I don't see the `containerPort` field in the YAML config of my workload that I shared.

Comment: @Nosail please read doc, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/

Comment: thanks @xirehat i have updated the container spec for deployment but still it doesn't work.

Comment: I have added the latest configuration in my question.

Comment: @Nosail I think you need to set firewall rule in GCP

Comment: @xirehat which firewall rule and what traffic do I need to set please?

Comment: @Nosail you must set a rule to accept request from `0.0.0.0/0` to Kubernetes cluster IPs. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls

Comment: The firewall rules were automatically created: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules#firewall_rules I see them in console.

Comment: Can someone please assist me where i am going wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the output of `kubectl describe service food-for-worms-service` ?

Comment: Also - just to better test something, can you replace the image you are using in your deployment with `us-docker.pkg.dev/gari-test/samples/node-app:v1.0`?  and redeploy?

Comment: @GariSingh I have added the output of `kubectl describe service food-for-worms-service` to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your app is listening on localhost, which works fine when you directly run the app on a host (like your laptop).  But when you run it in a container, binding to localhost inside the container means that the app won't be exposed outside the container itself.  So you need to change (or omit) the hostname in your app.

You can set the `hostname` to `0.0.0.0` so that your app will listen on all container addresses:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 9000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Do not have an inflated sense of yourself. You are just food for worms.');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

You can omit the hostname altogether (and your app will listen on all container addresses:

```
const http = require('http');

const port = 9000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Do not have an inflated sense of yourself. You are just food for worms.');
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`HTTP server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for leading me to a solution. The problem was with the app listening on localhost. It works now!